# OkHttp how to set maximum connection pool size (not max idle connections)

Tags: connection-pooling, okhttp

In OkHttp I cannot find a way to set a hard maximum connection pool size. From the documentation https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ConnectionPool.html it is clear that you can set a maximum idle connections, but not an overall max. That means that with high load it can grow beyond any limit.

Is there a way to maximize the pool? If not, why not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Connections are either active and held by a particular in-flight call, or idle and in the pool. Limit the total number of connections by limiting the number of threads executing HTTP calls. If you’re using `Call.execute()` (synchronous) just size your thread pool appropriately. If you’re using `Call.enqueue()` (asynchronous) the limits are in `Dispatcher`.

Comment: I'm using OkHttp in an appserver. Does this mean that it expects to be wrapped in its own thread pool?

Comment: Nope, that's not necessary. If you're making HTTP requests from another thread, such as your servlet thread, you do have to decide between sync and async however.

Comment: Thanks. It actually makes a lot of sense. I also see that the dispatcher takes an optional executor service which might be handy in our case.

Comment: @JesseWilson I'm using sync request. Could I set the total maximum connections in the pool, or I have to control the number of threads executing HTTP calls by myself? I tested on my local, but the connectionCounts is much higher than the idleConnectionCount

Comment: Set the number of threads yourself to limit total concurrency for synchronous calls.