# Retrofit & OkHttp - Is it possible to send only one request at a time?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using Retrofit 2.4.0 to send requests to a server. But sometimes server blocking my request if it has a similar timestamp in milliseconds with another request. I need to send request one at a time:

> 1. Request A is sent
> 2. Request B waits until the response for Request A received
> 3. Request A completes with success or error
> 4. Request B is sent

Is it possible to create such queue with Retrofit and OkHttp libraries?

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46210009/2837971 and this could be more helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/48497070/2837971

Comment: you can use asyntask for your requirement or the issue occurring using httpurlconnectionclass

Comment: Use RxJava for Sync calls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062485/rxjava-how-to-emit-observables-synchronously

Comment: Use RxJava for synchronous calls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062485/rxjava-how-to-emit-observables-synchronously

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I decided to use Dispatcher's setMaxRequests method to send request one at a time:

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
dispatcher.setMaxRequests(1);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .dispatcher(dispatcher)
                .build()
```

Comment: What will happen to any request raised after this request?

Comment: @Akki `maxRequests` actually refers to maximum *concurrent* requests, not total requests.

Answer (score 0):

yes you just need to call the function or send request on success/failure result of the API

```
  private void firstRequest() {


    Call<LoginModel> call= apiInterface.getLogin("");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginModel> call, Response<LoginModel> response) {
            //function here

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginModel> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this way, I need to change everywhere in my code. I decided to use Dispatcher's setMaxRequests method as Arnab Kundu suggested.

Comment: Though it can work like this, a more general solution is using a dispatcher as Joe responded.